# How to eliminate indentation when using command "\For{}" in the "algorithm environment"

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, pseudocode, algpseudocode

I do not want an indentation for the "For loop." How can I make it aligned with the **"Require"** text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require This is the input \textbf{Input}
\For{Here I do not want indentation}
\State Please delete the indentation for the for loop after the \textbf{Require}
\EndFor \\
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually that's the normal margin, but `\Require` doesn't use it, that's why it looks like the for is indented. You could try with `\algrenewcommand\Require{\item[\kern1em\algorithmicrequire]}`.